# Custom comment access

Tags: 7, users, comments

I need to prevent users from posting comments based on some conditions but I can't find any hooks I can implement.

For nodes we have `hook_node_access()` but apparently there is no `hook_comment_access()`

Any ideas on how I can implement this?

I have tried something like this but apparently it doesn't work:

```
function my_module_entity_info(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info["comment"]["access callback"] = "my_module_comment_access_callback";
}

function my_module_comment_access_callback($op, $comment){
  // some custom logic and return false...
  //...
  return comment_access($op, $comment);
}
```

My form is a custom form, displayed on multiple pages. I would like to prevent access to the comment entity and not to the form or page.

Answer (score 2):

You can get code from [Comment Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_perm) and [Comment Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/commentaccess) modules.

something like

```
function comment_perm_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  #comment_node_merci_reservation_form
  if ($form['#id'] == 'comment-form' and arg(0) == 'comment') {
    $types = variable_get('comment_perm_node_types', array());
    $form_id_types = array();
    if (is_array($types)) {
      foreach ($types as $type) {
        if ($form_id == 'comment_node_' . $type . '_form') {

          $nid = $form['nid']['#value'];
          if (! comment_perm_access($nid)) {
            // for comment reply pages, redirect back to the node
            if (arg(0) == 'comment' && arg(1) == 'reply' && is_numeric(arg(2))) {
              drupal_set_message(_comment_perm_access_denied_message($nid), 'error');
              drupal_goto('node/' . arg(2));
    }
  }

          if (arg(0) == 'comment' && arg(2) == 'edit' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
            if (! comment_perm_edit_access($nid)) {
              drupal_set_message(_comment_perm_access_denied_message($nid), 'error');
              drupal_goto('node/' . $nid);
            }
          }
      }
  }
    }
  }

}
```

then you can add you own condition.

You can also use above module ,if it is fulfilling your requirement.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for but maybe there is no other possibility to do this. I would like to prevent access to the comment entity and not to the form or page.

Answer (score 1):

Good answer from @visabhishek, will try something similar, but more minimal:

```
function youmodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // You can add more specific conditions here based on your reqs
  if ($form['#id'] == 'comment-form' && _your_conditions_callback() ) {        
      $form['#disabled'] = true;
      $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="messages warning"><h2>Not allowed</h2></div>';
  }
}

function _your_conditions_callback() {
  // Conditions block
  // return true;

  return false;
}
```

Maybe this helps as well, with lot less overhead.