# Access to each comment per user level

Tags: 8, hooks, comments

I have a system which allows tagging users to a node. I would like to restrict the access to the comments so that the tagged user can see only the the future comments. So he cannot see the comments added to that node before he is tagged.

Is there some hooks like `hook_node_access_records` for comments entity.

Comment: There isn't, comments only have the basic permissions provided by core. There are ways though, see the modules mentioned in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196498/custom-comment-access for some inspiration